# How should I set CCGMS on my Commodore 64 to login to a Linux machine?

Tags: commodore-64, terminal, network, linux, old-hardware-adaptation

I have a Strikelink WiFi modem for the C64 (see [here](https://1200baud.wordpress.com/2017/03/04/build-your-own-9600-baud-c64-wifi-modem-for-20/) and [here](https://www.tindie.com/products/topsider/strikelink-wifi-modem-c64-designed-by-alwyz/)) and I can connect to a BBS without issues using [CCGMS 2017 v4](https://csdb.dk/release/?id=154515) and the following settings:
**Baud = 9600

Modem Type = UP9600 / EZ232**

For this reason I use the same settings also to connect to a Linux machine that is running Telnet Server (the official **telnetd**, works perfectly if I connect to it using another Linux machine).

If I type `atdt192.x.y.z` (clearly my Linux machine ip) I see it gets to the login prompt but the characters are all garbled graphics and at this point the terminal is stuck:

[image: Screenshot of failed connection]

I use CCGMS 2017 v4 but I am more than happy to change it to [whatever version](https://1200baud.wordpress.com/category/ccgms/) can work better for this scenario.
I am also open to use other software that can make the connection to a Linux machine running Telnet possible.

What am I doing wrong?

In case I need to provide more details / info to allow further troubleshooting please let me know what is needed and I will update this question with all the data I am able to find.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135289/discussion-on-question-by-pitto-how-should-i-set-ccgms-on-my-commodore-64-to-log).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Before changing settings, display the current settings using `AT&V` and make a note of their values**

**TLDR**

Sending the following to the Strikelink may get things working:

```
ATNET1
ATPET=0
AT&W
```

If this doesn't work scroll down for an alternative connection method.

---

**Analysis**

The graphics characters displayed on the screenshot you [posted in the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60812761#60812761) looked a lot like TELNET protocol negotiation.  I [decoded the characters](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/C64_Petscii_Charts.png) as follows:

[image: Image of characters displayed on C64 screen at connect time]

| Hex | Decimal* | TELNET |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `7F` `7D` ??? | `255` `252` ??? | `IAC` `WONT` ??? |
| `7F` `7D` `20` | `255` `252` `32` | `IAC` `WONT` Terminal speed |
| `7F` `7D` `23` | `255` `252` `35` | `IAC` `WONT` X display location |
| `7F` `7D` `27` | `255` `252` `39` | `IAC` `WONT` Telnet environment |

<sup>* I've set the high bit of the decimal values for the first two bytes of each command (`IAC` and the command number)</sup>

As you can see these appear to be (mangled) TELNET handshake commands (see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200622032658/http://mars.netanya.ac.il/%7Eunesco/cdrom/booklet/HTML/NETWORKING/node300.html) and [here](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Internet/node141.html)).  It looks like the high bits are being stripped and low bytes (<0x20 i.e. <32 decimal) are not being displayed (indicated by ???).

I took a look at the source code for both CCGMS 2017<sup>1</sup> and Strikelink<sup>2</sup>.  Here's what I found:

**CCGMS**

The receive and transmit code appears to be 8-bit clean<sup>3</sup>.  The only thing unusual is that it reorders the bits read<sup>4</sup> (and written) using a precomputed<sup>5</sup> lookup table and a conditional addition for bit 7.

**Strikelink**

Looking through the options<sup>6</sup> there are two that stood out:

- `ATNETn` (*`n`* = `0` or `1`) 
  Disable or enable TELNET protocol handling 
  Enabling this enables TELNET command/escape handling, responds to all `DO` requests with a `WONT`, responds to all `WILL` offers with a `DO`, and halves the usable receive buffer size (to allow for character escapes)<sup>7</sup>.  No escapes are done on transmit<sup>8</sup>.  Note that this is not full TELNET support but it might be sufficient for your use-case.
- `ATPET=n` (*`n`* = `0` or `1`) 
  Disable or enable PET MCTerm translation 
  When enabled (with `ATPET=1`) this clears the high bit<sup>9</sup> before sending it to the C64.

I think that running `ATNET1` and `ATPET=0` may<sup>10</sup> get things working the way you want.  If all is working you can save the settings with `AT&W`

**Alternative connection method**

If connecting via TELNET fails to work you can try connecting to a raw TCP socket on the Linux host.  To do this (assuming a Debian system like the Raspberry Pi) run the following on the Linux host: `sudo apt-get install netcat` followed by `netcat -lvp 2323 -e /bin/bash`  You should now be able to turn off TELNET support on the Strikelink (with `ATNET0`) and connect to the Linux host on port 2323.  Note that this method is horribly insecure (even worse than TELNET) so only do this if you're on a private network (e.g. 192.168.x.x) and don't care about the security of the Linux host.

---

<sup>1</sup> [CCGMS 2017 v6 source](https://csdb.dk/release/download.php?id=193694) from [here](https://csdb.dk/release/?id=156523) (The source for v4 does not seem to be available)

<sup>2</sup> [Strikelink firmware source](http://www.mediafire.com/file/tm71a1oa1a3macc/alwyz_modded_firmware.rar) from [here](https://1200baud.wordpress.com/2017/03/04/build-your-own-9600-baud-c64-wifi-modem-for-20/) (This is the only firmware source link I could find)

<sup>3</sup> I'm not very good with [6502 assembler](http://www.6502.org/tutorials/6502opcodes.html) so I could be mistaken.

<sup>4</sup> CCGMS receive routine bit reordering code (`ccsrc.txt` lines 8144-8152):

```
    lda  $dd0c              ; read SDR (bit0=databit7,...,bit7=databit0)
    cmp  #128               ; move bit7 into carry-flag
    and  #127
    tax
    lda  revtabup,x           ; read databits 1-7 from lookup table
    adc  #0                 ; add databit0
    ldx  wr_rptr            ; and write it into the receive buffer
    sta  recbufup,x
    inx
```

<sup>5</sup> CCGMS look-up table population code (`ccsrc.txt` lines 8197-8209):

```
    lda  $dd0d              ; check for bit3 (SDR-flag)
    and  #8
    
    ldx  #0
-   stx  outstat            ; outstat used as temporary variable
    ldy  #8
-   asl  outstat
    ror  a
    dey
    bne  -
    sta  revtabup,x
    inx
    bpl  --
```

<sup>6</sup> Strikelink options (adapted from `juno12.ino` lines 561-588):

```
DISPLAY HELP..: AT?
or............: ATHELP
DIAL HOST.....: ATDTHOST:PORT
SPEED DIAL....: ATDSN (N=0-9)
SET SPEED DIAL: AT&ZN=HOST:PORT (N=0-9)
HANDLE TELNET.: ATNETN (N=0,1)
PET MCTERM TR.: ATPET=N (N=0,1)
NETWORK INFO..: ATI
HTTP GET......: ATGET<URL>
AUTO ANSWER...: ATS0=N (N=0,1)
SET BUSY MSG..: AT$BM=YOUR BUSY MESSAGE
LOAD NVRAM....: ATZ
SAVE TO NVRAM.: AT&W
SHOW SETTINGS.: AT&V
FACT. DEFAULTS: AT&F
PIN POLARITY..: AT&PN (N=0/INV,1/NORM)
ECHO OFF/ON...: ATE0 / ATE1
VERBOSE OFF/ON: ATV0 / ATV1
SET SSID......: AT$SSID=WIFISSID
SET PASSWORD..: AT$PASS=WIFIPASSWORD
SET BAUD RATE.: AT$SB=N (3,12,24,48,96
                192,384,576,1152)*100
FLOW CONTROL..: AT&KN (N=0/N,1/HW,2/SW)
WIFI OFF/ON...: ATC0 / ATC1
HANGUP........: ATH
ENTER CMD MODE: +++
EXIT CMD MODE.: ATO
QUERY MOST COMMANDS FOLLOWED BY '?'
```

Note that the above isn't exactly correct.  If you're having trouble setting an option try omitting the `=` from the command or adding a `=` before the option value.

<sup>7</sup> See `juno12.ino` lines 1354-1402.

<sup>8</sup> This means that `0xff` (decimal 255, TELNET `IAC`) cannot be sent from the C64 when TELNET mode is enabled on the Strikelink.  (Well technically it can, you just have to send it twice.)

<sup>9</sup> Strikelink MCTerm high bit bit-clearing option (`juno12.ino` lines 1397-1402):

```
  // Fix PET MCTerm 1.26C Pet->ASCII encoding to actual ASCII
  if (petTranslate == true) {
    for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (txBuf[i] > 127) txBuf[i]-= 128;
    }
  }
```

<sup>10</sup> It might be the case that Strikelink's TELNET support is insufficient.  Looking through the code it looks like there is only support for responding to `DO` and `WILL` commands, not `DONT` or `WONT`.  Adding appropriate responses for the latter two to `juno12.ino` would largely be a matter of cut and paste (have `DONT` give a `WONT` response and `WONT` a `DONT`); e.g. insert the following at line 1450:

```
      else if (cmdByte1 == DONT)
      {
        tcpClient.write((uint8_t)255); tcpClient.write((uint8_t)WONT); tcpClient.write(cmdByte2);
      }
      else if (cmdByte1 == WONT)
      {
        tcpClient.write((uint8_t)255); tcpClient.write((uint8_t)DONT); tcpClient.write(cmdByte2);
      }
```

Comment: Short question: is it really `ATNETN (N=0,1)`  but `ATPET=N (N=0,1)` ?

Comment: @Raffzahn Yes, it really is (even though the original help text claims otherwise).  See `juno12.ino` lines 897, 902, 1134, and 1140.

Comment: No need to look up, I trust your research. Made me just stumble.

Comment: @Raffzahn Yea, surprised me too.  (re: line #s: I still had `juno12.ino` open on my screen so why not give them)

Comment: Who... Are... YOU?! =:O
This is just...
Genius, admirable.
I will make a pdf of this, print it in good paper and put it in the c64 original instruction box.
I will hopefully try this tonight and report, now I have to go and get my jaw on the floor.

Comment: @Pitto Honestly, I don't have high hopes for TELNET unless you make the change in footnote 10 (do try it out though).  The alternative connection method (raw TCP using `netcat`) should work fine though if TELNET doesn't work.  Best of success!

Comment: I can't wait to test...
But I have to wait to be under cover of darkness :D

Take me with you, Master, show me the ways.
I will be your padawan.

Comment: It works like a champion! Hat tip to you, sir.